# Android HTML5 game audio auto played

Tags: android, html, html5-audio

I am working on an Android application which includes a HTML5 game which uses LimeJS!. My situation is:

When my HTML5 activity is opened which runs with WebView, then the audio in the game is played, then pressed back to exit activity. And when notification is notified after HTML5 activity exited with sound, the audio in game that played before will play again!

In LogCat in got this when game audio started:

```
AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42e84518Handler (android.webkit.HTML5Audio) {42d93ef8}
```

I want to know how to stop this audio focus from HTML5Audio.